# Change Date Format On Form View Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10, odoo-view

I am using the date field on form view using below code:

```
<field name="date_order" />
```

I will display **DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS**.

But, I want to hide seconds on form view.

I need to show like: **DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM** on form view.

Answer (score 2):

It's a global setting in Odoo in every language. In debug mode under `Settings/Translations/Languages` you are able to set up a date and time format for every language. But as i said, it will change the format of every datetime or date field in Odoo client.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i just want to format a particular field format not for all the fields.

Comment: For future reference: I came across this `t-options='{"hide_seconds": True}` in odoo base code which you can try and check if this works, if this does not work try with  `options='{"hide_seconds": True}`